# Access: Multiple user edditing, Warning msg

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database which is shared on a network between multiple user. When different users open the database and edit the data, it is not an issue.
However, if one record being opened by multiple users, the second user gets the form as Read-only and his db freezes, so he has to close db completely.

I want to know how I can write a code to bring a msgbox with close option so he can close and edit another record.

Thanks

Comment: It is not normal behaviour for Access to "freeze" in this scenario. What are the settings for **RecordLocks** and **RecordsetType** properties in your form?

Answer (score 1):

Access actually comes (OOTB) with what you're describing, see here:

> In a multiuser database, you can use the No Locks setting if you want to use optimistic locking and **warn users attempting to edit the same record on a form.** You can use the Edited Record setting if you want to prevent two or more users editing data at the same time.

From [Here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/RecordLocks-Property-6ca29bbb-8824-4671-8087-97fe0568019a)

So, in VB for tighter control:

`Forms("MyFormName").RecordLocks = 2`

> (Forms and queries only) A page of records is locked as soon as any user starts editing any field in the record and stays locked until the user moves to another record. Consequently, a record can be edited by only one user at a time. This is also called "pessimistic" locking.

Comment: I know about these options which are also available through the form design. My issue is that at the moment on the Edited Record, the second user get trapped inside the form so he cannot exit the form (because the form is locked and it can not be closed) and the only option is to close down the whole access. What I wanted was a how detect if someone is editing the record before you open the form (terminating an operation or close down the form if someone is editing the record).

Comment: He can always press **Esc** (multiple times if necessary) to undo his changes and be able to close the form.